# How to delete record from selected row datagridview and update database after deleted?

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms

I'm trying to build a winform with a Delete button and DataGridView. What I want is to click a row in DatagridView and then click Delete button. The selected row will be removed from DataGridView and database too. Here's my uncompleted code:

```
private void btnDelete_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (dgvKH.SelectedRows.Count > 0)
            {
                int selectedIndex = dgvKH.SelectedRows[0].Index;

            }
            Load();
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it depends on your datagridview. if it has some sort of primary key you can do that by update Query. here is some code

```
    private void btnDelete_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (dgvKH.SelectedRows.Count > 0)
        {
            int selectedIndex = dgvKH.SelectedRows[0].Index;
            int PrimaryKey =Convert.ToInt32(dgvKH.Rows[selectedIndex].Cells["ID"].Value);
            /*
             * Execute this Query HERE. 
               string sql = "DELETE From MyTable WHERE ID = " + PrimaryKey;
            */

            dgvKH.Rows.RemoveAt(selectedIndex);

        }
        Load();
    }
```

Comment: Great! :D  Glad i could help!